# speed-up a function with comparison in python

Tags: python

I have a function dominates() that seems to be the bottleneck of my algorithm (after profiling it). the function is as follows:

```
    def dominates(self, label1: Label, label2: Label):
        if label1.cost - label1.maxP * label1.ratePiP <= label2.cost - label2.maxP * label2.ratePiP:
            if label1.loadF <=  label2.loadF:
                if label1.part <=  label2.part :
                    if label1.cost - (label2.loadF - label1.loadF) * label1.ratePiP <=  label2.cost :
                        if label1.cost - (label2.loadF + label2.maxP - label1.loadF) * label1.ratePiP <= label2.cost - label2.maxP * label2.ratePiP :
                            if all(l1 <=l2 for l1,l2 in zip(label1.custk, label2.custk)):
                                return label2
        else:
            if label1.loadF >= label2.loadF:
                if label1.part >= label2.part:
                    if label1.cost - (label2.loadF - label1.loadF) * label1.ratePiP >= label2.cost :
                        if label1.cost - (label2.loadF + label2.maxP - label1.loadF) * label1.ratePiP >=label2.cost - label2.maxP * label2.ratePiP:
                            if all(l1>= l2 for l1, l2 in zip(label1.custk, label2.custk)):
                                return label1
```

`label.cost` and `label.ratePiP` are floats and `label.part` and `label.loadF` and `label.maxP` are integers while `label.custk` is array.array.
The number of calls is quite high (25,000,000+ times) and have done my best to reduce it. I am now testing on small instances and it does not seem ok for me to have that much time spent on this function (28971 ms) for small instances. Any idea how to speed it up?

Comment: Having such deeply nested `if` statements is generally an anti-pattern https://medium.com/madhash/pyramid-of-doom-the-signs-and-symptoms-of-a-common-anti-pattern-c716838e1819 also I would try asking this on code review exchange if you aren't seeing a specific error and looking for general performance improvements

Comment: If you're looking for optimization help, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask

Comment: @sos function seems simple. Implement it in C/C++ and call through CPython or Bootst.Python

Comment: Not really sure what the if conditions are trying to calculate. Mabye tell us what problem you are trying to solve, and people here might suggest a faster more efficient approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will ask in code review. should I close this question then or ..?

Comment: @DollarAkshay it is quite complicated to explain the framework but basically these  conditions are dominance rules between labels for a specific problem (there is some Operations Research math behind it). so if all the first conditions are true then label2 is dominated and if the second set of conditions is true then label1 is dominated otherwise we cannot conclude and it just returns None.

Comment: @warchantua *implement this in x language* is not at all helpful

Comment: And the bottleneck is not in `all()` and `zip()`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller no, `zip` does not appear in the profiling and `all()`  only takes 2870ms and it is called from another function.

Comment: Are you familiar with numba? I have used it to speed up a lot of CPU-intensive calculations that lend themselves to numpy. Of course I don't know if it would work in your case

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous never heard of it but will check it thanks!